# How to add a element into another list at a certain index without removing or replacing any elements scala

Tags: arrays, list, algorithm, scala

I have a  List and Map as below,

```
 val exampleList = List("A","B","C","D","E","A","L","M","N")
 val exampleMap = Map("W1" -> Vector(4,8),
                      "W2"  -> Vector(5)
                     )
```

So I need to add all the letters in the exampleMap to the exampleList according to the values (indexes that should take places in the exampleList) that in the exampleMap. So the final output should be something like this

`val result = List("A","B","C","D","W1","E","W1","A","L","M","W1","N")`

I tried several ways using foldLeft as well as using flatMap but still not get any luck.

Comment: Have you tried `zipWithIndex` first? Like e.g. `exampleList.zipWithIndex.flatMap { case (value, index) => ... }`?

Comment: I would solve this using a tail-recursive algorithm, also it may help to invert the `Map`

Comment: 1. Invert the map: make it map indices to elements `4 -> W1, 8 -> W1, 5 -> W2` 
2. `exampleList.zipWithIndex` - pair each element with an index
3. `foldRight` the paired collection, starting with an empty list. If index is in the reveresed map, prepend the corresponding element to the result. Always prepend the original element. 
4. post any specific problems you run into along with your code showing how to reproduce

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use tail recursion manually, you can use all the provided methods of List and Map:

```
val exampleList = List("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "A", "L", "M", "N")
val exampleMap = Map("W1" -> Vector(4, 8), "W2" -> Vector(5))

// assumes that there is only 1 append per index
val appendedByIndex = for {
  (value, indices) <- exampleMap
  index <- indices
} yield index -> value

exampleList.zipWithIndex.flatMap { case (value, index) =>
  appendedByIndex
    .get(index + 1) // appended has index bigger by 1 than current value 
    .fold(List(value))(appended => List(value, appended))
}
// List("A","B","C","D","W1","E","W2","A","L","M","W1","N")
```

Comment: This getting a error in here "appendedByIndex
    .get(index + 1)" :/

Comment: Works for me with the data you provided in example: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/s6IsmD9gRUWkejtDuY80Zw, check your data and your assertions (0-indexed vs 1-indexed etc)